# What is the difference between gcswf32.dll and NPSWF32.dll

Tags: browser, adobe, flash

What are the specific differences between the flash plugin implementations from Google and Adobe? Please respond with specific, concrete, known differences and not with speculation.

Comment: What makes you think there is a difference?  Google probably isn't going to document it if they didn't change anything.